# Get product's category ids and names

Tags: magento

There is this method `getCategoryIds()` in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product`. This method returns all category IDs of requested product. I need to modify the `SELECT` statement so it will return also category names.

Here is the basic query:

```
$select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
    ->from($this->_productCategoryTable, 'category_id')
    ->where('product_id=?', $product->getId());
```

I can't use `catalog_category_flat` table to for some reasons, so I have to use EAV tables. So at this point I have this query:

```
$select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
    ->from($this->_productCategoryTable, 'category_id')
    ->where('catalog_category_product.product_id=?', $product->getId())
    ->join(
       array('a' =>'catalog_category_entity_varchar'),
       'a.entity_id = catalog_category_product.category_id',
       array('name' => 'value')
    )
    ->join(
       array('b' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute')),
       'b.attribute_id = a.attribute_id',
       array()
    )
    ->where("b.attribut_code = 'name'");
```

This works, but I'd like to ask if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest and probably cleanest:

```
$categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

Then you can simply traverse the collection:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    var_dump($category->getName());
}
```

Comment: This certainly works, yet execution time of this approach is higher that above query with 2 joins. I forgot to mention that performance has to be taken into account. But difference is only few ms, so I might use it, though. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ventus: I guess a matter of personal preference, but I'd much prefer to take the couple ms (if even that) performance hit vs. having to rewrite the resourceModel...

Comment: If you'd like to save a few ms, unless this query is run many many times per second, optimizations to page rendering time will probably easily outweigh the cost of this query. The maintenance time for rewriting a resourceModel is a bit... pernicious, so I'd recommend Daniel's solution as well.

Comment: Yes, yours suggestions were correct. This approach is much better than messing with resource model. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSloof thanks a ton! my product was not returning category id, and had wasted too long trying different things. But this method returned all assigned categories. voted up and bowed!

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: [Joining an EAV table](http://codegento.com/2011/03/joining-an-eav-table-to-flat-table/) and made the function, which will add the category join query, use it from the collection.

Just call this function from the code this way:

```
// To join the name of category
$this->joinCategoryAttribute('<your table alias>.category_id', 'name');
```

And this is the function:

```
public function joinCategoryAttribute($joinOriginId, $code)
{
    $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_category', $code);
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('catalog_category');
    $attribute = Mage::getModel($entityType->getAttributeModel())->load($attributeId);
    $entityTable = $this->getTable($entityType->getEntityTable());
    $alias = 'table' . $code;
    $table = $entityTable . '_' . $attribute->getBackendType();
    $field = $alias . '.value';
    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array($alias => $table),
                "{$joinOriginId} = {$alias}.entity_id AND {$alias}.attribute_id = " . $attribute->getAttributeId(),
                array($attribute->getAttributeCode() => $field)
        );
    return $this;
}
```