# Get attribute label (url identifier) - Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, label

On a product page I need the label text from the current manufacturer.

I know how to get the ID and Text with this code example:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);

/** Get manufacturer name*/
    $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');

/** Get manufacturer id*/
$manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
```

How can I get the label?

Example: 
 
manufacturer = Emporio Armani
id = 36 
label (url identifier) = **emporioarmani**

I need the label (url identifier).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024808/get-products-category-ids-and-names

Comment: `<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('keyingredients')->getFrontendLabel(); ?>`
I am not answering it, its already answered here [http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/](http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/)

Comment: What do you mean by "label (url identifier)"? Enumerated attribute options have four data: value_id, option_id, store_id, and value (ref `eav_attribute_option_value` table).

Comment: Excuse me, I'd like you to explain in more detail.
Imagine you have an attribute 'Manufacturer'. Then you have an URL-Identifier (seo). In my case: 
/f/manufacturer/emporioarmani

I've uploaded an image:
http://imageshack.us/f/211/bildschirmfoto20121125uh.png/

I need the column 'URL-Bezeichner' which is in german. It's called URL-Identifier in english.

Answer (score 0):

This exists in the realm of EAV config. It's important to understand this as a precondition to appreciating the **catalog_product**-specific convenience methods for retrieving attribute info.

Whereas attributes can be uniquely identified by `attribute_code` + `entity_type_id`, it's possible to retrieve all of any attribute's meta information through the `eav/config` model:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'manufacturer'
);
```

This is the main representation of the entity attribute. From this instance one can retrieve all sorts of information - including the proper frontend label for the given store:

```
echo $attribute->getStoreLabel();
//or $attribute->getStoreLabel([store id]);
```

Comment: I've been trying to get the label with that code above but it didn't work for me. I always get the word 'Manufacturer' but not the value -> in this case 'emporioarmani'. Can you give me another example or specific code example?

Comment: Sorry, I saw "label" in your question and answered that.

Comment: No worry, thank you for helping me. I've uploaded an image within my comment above. Perhaps it is more specific.